# Charge distribution and potential changes on earthing for conductors placed close to each other?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, conductors

Suppose we have two conducting plates with charges $2Q$ and $3Q$ placed close to each other (ignore edge effects for simplicity).

[image]It is clear that when the switch is open, the charge distribution is (can be found by using the fact that electric field inside the material of the plates would be zero) $\frac{5Q}{2}$ on surfaces $A$ and $D$, and surface $B$ has charge $-\frac{Q}{2}$, while surface $C$ has charge $\frac{Q}{2}$.

My doubt however, arises here. If we were to close the switch (that is, earth the right plate), would the charge distribution change? How? My friends say that now the total charge of the system would be zero, and surfaces $A$ and $D$ would have zero charges, and $B$ would have $2Q$, and $C$ would have $-2Q$ charge. They say they do not have an explanation for it, and that it is a glitch they cannot answer. I think that if they were spherical conductors, I would've written net potential at surface $D$ in terms of the final charge acquired by the earthed plate and equated  it to zero(or potential of the earth).

But now, how would we write the potential of the two plates finally? What would the final charge distribution look like and why?

Comment: Can someone answer this? Is this a potential unexplainable glitch?